# Speeding up this Javasctipt string manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I am changing the content of about 5000 HTML tags and as I read here doing 5000+ html rendering changes is slow and it is better just to redraw the HTML once,

Therefor I have created a function that loads the entire HTML into a JavaScript string and then goes through the text(looking for a label tag), changes the content of the tags and eventually redraws the HTML once.

With high hopes, this was also a failure and takes around 30 seconds on a 1000 tags test.

My function basically reverse counts all the visible label DIVs on the screen and adds numbering to them,

Here's the code, what am I doing wrong please? (here's an isolated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzvish/eLbTy/8/)

```
// Goes through all visible entries on the page and updates their count value
function updateCountLabels()    {
        var entries        = document.getElementsByName('entryWell');
        var entriesId      = document.getElementsByName('entryId');
        var entriesHtml    = document.getElementById('resultContainer').innerHTML;
        var visibleEntries = new Array();
        var countEntries = 0 , pointer = 0;

        // Create a list of all visible arrays:
        for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)    {
            if ($(entries[i]).is(":visible")) {
                countEntries++;
                visibleEntries.push(entriesId[i].value);
            }
        }

        // Update html of all visible arrays with numbering:
        for (i = 0; i < visibleEntries.length; i++)            {
            currentId   = visibleEntries[i];

            // Get the position of insertion for that label element:
            elementHtml = '<div id="entryCount'+currentId+'" class="entryCountLabel label label-info">';

            pointer    = entriesHtml.indexOf(elementHtml) + elementHtml.length;
            pointerEnd = entriesHtml.indexOf("</div>",pointer);

            entriesHtml = entriesHtml.substring(0, pointer) + countEntries + entriesHtml.substring(pointerEnd);

            countEntries--;
        }

        // apply the new modified HTML:
        document.getElementById('resultContainer').innerHTML = entriesHtml;
}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle so we can see the HTML too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kA2zf/ - still a work in progress though as there's some error there I havent found

Comment: Well, your fiddle in its current form doesn’t say much about the actual problem. Some hints: 1) `div` elements do not have a `name` attribute, so don’t rely on that to select them; use a class or something instead. 2) `is(":visible")` is probably quite costly – don’t you have another way of determining whether or not an element is visible, a class maybe?

Comment: 3) Yes, DOM manipulation in large amounts is costly, especially if done in a way that the browser has to update after every operation. You might a) be better of with not doing this with `.innerHTML`, but real DOM methods instead, and b) you should do this “outside” of the DOM – f.e. by cloning the parent element first, do manipulation on the elements, and then when that is done replace the whole parent element with the clone.

Comment: here's an updated and working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzvish/eLbTy/3/

Comment: Still looking for a solution - updated the fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/tzvish/eLbTy/6/

Comment: Can you please provide a sample string of what the initial HTML is and what the modified HTML should look like?

Comment: yes Nit, it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/tzvish/eLbTy/7

Comment: Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzvish/eLbTy/8/

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html):

> Loops are frequently found to be bottlenecks in JavaScript. To make a loop the most efficient, reverse the order in which you process the items so that the control condition compares the iterator to zero. This is far faster than comparing a value to a nonzero number and significantly speeds up array processing. If there are a large number of required iterations, you may also want to consider using Duff’s Device to speed up execution.

So change:

```
for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
```

To

```
for (i = entries.length - 1; i ==0 ; i--)
```

Also notice following paragraph from mentioned link:

> Be careful when using HTMLCollection objects. Each time a property is accessed on one of these objects, it requires a query of the DOM for matching nodes. This is an expensive operation that can be avoided by accessing HTMLCollection properties only when necessary and storing frequently used values (such as the length property) in local variables.

So change:

```
for (i = entries.length - 1; i == 0; i--)
```

To:

```
var len = entries.length;
for (i = len - 1; i ==0 ; i--)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not faster :(
maybe you can check my fiddle, each button represents a method.
http://jsfiddle.net/tzvish/eLbTy/6/

Comment: First of all, `i == 0` is incorrect and will not process the array at all. It also has the same speed http://jsperf.com/2131. Thirdly, changing how you loop is less than drop in the ocean when compared to the other actual work being done